# I can not find the element based on class_name, xpath, or id

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to download a web table into a csv file.  I can find a list of table cells using find_elements_by_class_name. But once I get the list of cells, I can not get the component within that cell. I tried find_elements_by_xpath, find_elements_by_id, find_elements_by_class_name.
Can someone look at the code and let me know what I should change? Thanks!
'''

```
from selenium import webdriver
url='https://www.i-recruit.com/recruiter_listing.php?s=578'
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
firms=driver.find_elements_by_class_name('exec-rec-box')
for firm in firms:
    title=firm.find_element_by_class_name('exec_name').text
```

'''

Comment: what are the fields you require in your csv?

Comment: Can you clarify which part it is you’re struggling with?

Comment: It is the iteration part.
title=firm.find_element_by_class_name('exec_name').text

Answer (score 0):

Try using this way.

```
from selenium import webdriver
url='https://www.i-recruit.com/recruiter_listing.php?s=578'
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
services=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#recruiter-section-3 > div > div > div > div.row.services.padding_tb_60px')
for recruiter in services:
    firm=recruiter.find_element_by_class_name('exec-name').text
```

Comment: I tried your code. It works for getting the exec-name item.  But it only retrieves the first "service".  I need to retrieve all 500+ firm information on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
url='https://www.i-recruit.com/recruiter_listing.php?s=578'
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
services=driver.find_elements_by_class_name('exec-rec-box')
firm_list=[]
for recruiter in services:
    firmname=recruiter.find_element_by_class_name('exec-name').text
    firmskill=recruiter.find_element_by_class_name('exec-skill-matched-light').text
    firm_item={
        'name': firmname,
        'skill': firmskill,
    }
    firm_list.append(firm_item)

df=pd.DataFrame(firm_list)

print(df)
```